# processing data in kafka stream and filter and store

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I have some data in my kafak ([mydata](https://api.binance.com/api/v3/klines?symbol=BTCUSDT&interval=1m&startTime=1654121947000&endTime=1654241947000&limit=1000)).
I want to process those data with KafkaStream and then set [SMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moving_average#Simple_moving_average) on them.
how can I do that?
I'm so confused about processing data with kafka stream and how to store related object that will come in future.

these are some

```
    source.map((k, v) -> {
                try {
                    Candle candle = objectMapper.readValue(v, Candle.class);
                    return new KeyValue<>(k, candle);
                } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                return new KeyValue<>(k, v);
            })
            .filter((k, v) -> Double.parseDouble(((Candle) v).getClose()) > 29690)
            .peek((k, v) -> System.out.println(((Candle) v).getCloseTime()))
            .foreach((k, v) -> result.add((Candle) v));
```

```
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(kafkaStream::close));
    final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);
    kafkaStream.setStateListener((newState, oldState) -> {
    if (oldState == KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING && newState != KafkaStreams.State.RUNNING) {
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            });
    kafkaStream.start();
   
   try {
    
       latch.await();
       System.out.println(candles.size());
   
   } catch (final InterruptedException e) {
       throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: You need state (not some result arraylist; you should use a KTable instead here). You're only using stateless processors. Have you looked into using streaming windows or the aggregate function?

Comment: @OneCricketeer acctually I didn't use Ktable, but aggregate wasn't useful. because  when a new data comes in, I have to delete thee first data used in aggregation then add new data to my aggregated sum.

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't know how to do this with kafkastream.
I mean reading data. then get sum a field of data.
when a new data comes in, remove the first data from my sum then use new data for getting the avg of data.

Comment: If you use an arraylist as your initializer, then you can do whatever logic you want within the aggregator to remove elements from that list. You cannot sum without some type of grouping, and you can't get an SMA until you have at least K elements that are collected

Comment: Similar question here does averages over a sliding time window  https://stackoverflow.com/q/72468526/2308683 ; you should combine that with a [TimestampExtractor](https://kafka.apache.org/27/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/processor/TimestampExtractor.html) if you want to use timestamp from other sources within the record